# In MVC3 how do I have a dropdown that shows/hides fields based on the selected value?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a dropdown of countries, and an address form. Depending on the country selected, I want to hide/show certain fields. I'm quite new to MVC and MVC3, what is the best way to do this?

I have on the page a 'DropDownListFor' that populates correctly. When this changes, I imagine I need to ask the server which fields to show/hide. I could perhaps put some JQuery into a change event that calls a method, and it returns some json saying visible:true for each field, but I don't know if that's ideal or even how to implement it (possibly $.ajax or something).

Any ideas?

Edit: I should add the hard part of this is asking the server what fields to show for each country as there are many countries and the possibilities are all stored in the database. I am accustomed to webforms not MVC so I would ordinarily postback and have serverside logic, but this isn't an option with MVC afaik...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have deleted my first answer as it was irrelevant.

With MVC3 you can send an AJAX request to any method.

In `HomeController.cs`:

```
public List<string> GetFieldsToShow(string id)
{

   // if you routing is left to default, the parameter passed in will be called 'id'

   // Do what you gotta do...
   List<string> listOfFieldsToShowBasedOnCountry = GetList(id);
   return listOfFieldsToShowBasedOnCountry;
}
```

And in the AJAX call, something like...

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: '/Home/GetFieldsToShow/' + valueOfSelectedDropDownItem,
   /*etc...*/
   success: function(data){
      $(data).each(function(){
         $('#' + this).show();
      }
   }
});
```

Comment: This is the easy part, I have updated my question to explain that it's the dynamic aspect of working out which fields to show/hide that is tripping me up.

Comment: I've updated my answer, hopefully I've understood better this time!

Comment: Cheers that sounds great! I think your first answer was relevent for triggering the method above =)

Comment: You're right, but as it wasn't your question I thought I'd just remove it. Glad I could help =D